# Using backbone and passing a parameter to a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using **backbone.marionette** for view control.

My issue is **"How do you pass a parameter to a model?"**

This is what I have tried:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/CampaginModel',
    'collections/CampaignCollection',
    'text!templates/includes/_campaign.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, CampaginModel, CampaignCollection, campaignTemplate) {  
    var campaginView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: campaignTemplate,
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.campaign_id = options.id;
        },
        model: CampaginModel({id: this.campaign_id}),
        onRender: function () {
        }
    }); // end campagin view
    return campaginView;
});
```

I have noticed that my parameter get passed to the view init function I'm kinda stuck after this point. In standard backbone I just created a new model in the render function and passed the parameter to the model that way. However Marionette views have a 'model' attribute which I think should allow me to pass in it there, but it does not!

**Model:**

```
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'jquery'
], function (_, Backbone, jquery) {

    var CampaginModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: '/api/v1/campaign/',


        // Model Constructor
        initialize: function () {

        },


    });


    return CampaginModel;

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your file structure looks like.

But it should be like something like this.

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/CampaginModel',
    'collections/CampaignCollection',
    'text!templates/includes/_campaign.html'
], function ($, _, Backbone, CampaginModel, CampaignCollection, campaignTemplate) {

var campaginView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    template: campaignTemplate,

    initialize: function (options) {

        this.campaign_id = options.id;
        this.model.set({id: this.campaign_id});

    },
    model: CampaginModel,
    onRender: function () {
    }

}); // end campagin view


return campaginView;


});
```

I haven't test the code yet.

If you need to set your parameters to model, you have to use backbone's `model.set()` function

Comment: I see, I did read that but whenever I tried I got TypeError: Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'set'

Comment: can you post your code in `'models/CampaginModel'`, it probably something wrong there.  I think what cause the problem is that you haven't `var campaginModel = new CampaginModel`, is it?

Comment: Added the model to the question if you can take a look that would be cool.

Comment: where would I be adding var campaginModel = new CampaginModel? in the view init?

Comment: alright, here is the problem. Change `return new CampaginModel;` instead of `return CampaginModel;`